# How does Chesscube.com rating compare to USCF and FIDE ratings?

Tags: rating, fide, uscf

My Chesscube is 1800. I would like to have the strength of 2100 or 1900 USCF and FIDE. What Chesscube rating do I need?

Comment: Ratings only make sense within a given population of players, and perhaps to a lesser extent within a given type of time control (traditional, rapid, blitz).  I don't use Chesscube so can't answer directly - but, would it be possible to identify a group of players on Chesscube who are also rated in the USCF (or FIDE) system, for the type of time control you're interested?  Even though the rating systems are different, I would presume the players would play at the same strength within both systems, which would provide a basis for comparison.

Comment: My assumption would be that an online chess site like Chesscube would attract a larger population of very casual players, and since ratings compare the strength of players within the population, I would assume that the ratings would be inflated, in that it's probably easier to be a "good" player within the Chesscube population than within any of the traditional OTB chess systems - plus, my understanding is that Chesscube ratings start out higher to begin with (1500 starting rating on Chesscube, vs. an starting rating of 1200 for adult players in USCF).  How inflated over USCF, couldn't say...

Comment: As a single data point, my chesscube rating is 2450 and my USCF/FIDE ratings are about 2200/2100.

Answer (score 4):

**There is no way to directly compare ratings from distinct populations**.

**However, it's not true that online chess and OTB populations are really distinct**. There are players who have ratings in both OTB and online chess.

**So, you can compare your rating this way:** Find players in Chesscube who has also OTB ratings, select two of them, both have ratings close to your rating, one of them is higher than you, one of them is lower than you.

Your expected rating is between their OTB rating. If you pick more player from Chesscube, and pick more closer players, you will get smaller interval, thus more accurate estimate.

Example:

```
            Online    |    OTB
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Player A     1750     |    1630
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Player B     1850     |    1730
--------------------------------------------------------------------
You          1800     | Expected: ~1680, Probably between 1630-1730
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Along those lines, most sites like USCF and lichess are nice enough to offer you a rating distribution curve, often with percentiles.  Assuming players who play OTB, lichess, chess.com and ICC are from the same planet,  you could try to line up percentiles to see what ratings line up side-by-side.

For example:
- http://www.uschess.org/archive/ratings/ratedist.php (this is dated, but try downloading the actual current member stats as a Excel/CSV and come up with your own distribution)
- https://lichess.org/stat/rating/distribution/classical

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is very dependable.
Firstly, chesscube only has one rating (except if you are a premium), so I would say online ratings are quite unreliable to compare with real life chess ratings.

For example, chesscube and other chess sites ratings often start with 1500, and adjusts from there; whilst in real life, you start from 700 rating points, and then adjust from there.

In addition, there are many players in chess.com who have over 2300 rating points, but nearly none of them have a title.

Online gameplay depends more on who you are matched up against than that of real life. In real games, you often don't get to choose your opponents, and have to play with either someone significantly easier or quite harder. Online, you can adjust rating ranges and time limit, therefore it is easier to be matched up against one of similar strengths and etc.

Finally, there are some on the internet that are not really honest about their ratings (ie. cheaters, sandbaggers and boosters), and they can severely affect your rating points, while in real life, there are hardly any cheaters.

So I would say it is very challenging to compare the two scales, and to compare the two, you should really find someone who has a fide rating as well as their online ones, play them and then gauge your skill.

Good luck!