# How does Lichess rating compare to USCF?

Tags: rating, elo, uscf, glicko

Just wondering some examples of peoples' USCF rating to Lichess (classic lichess, 10 min+)

I know it's hard to compare different pools of players. But I think that considering how we do polling with sample sizes, the numbers could be similar once you have the appropriate offset calculated. I need examples of comparisons of the ratings, to know "what's the average offset"?

I figure if I am in the top 90% Percentile in lichess, then I should be at least top 70% in USCF or some comparison like that. (just as an example)

Comment: You cannot compare them and the reason has nothing to do with sample size. Also there is not going to be an "offset" or something like that.

Comment: As an unscientific statistic-of-one personal experience (and therefore worth what you paid for it - nothing), my USCF rating and lichess rating are several hundred points off - and, worse, seem to show no correlation.  At one point, my lichess skyrocketed and then slowly tapered off (with no change to USCF); at another, my USCF climbed (with no change to lichess).  /shrug.

Comment: I'd add that Lichess uses Stockfish so there's obviously a correlation between how Lichess calculates ratings and how Stockfish does given the same input data.

Comment: Please see these two questions for answer: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13324/whats-the-chess-website-with-the-most-correct-online-rating/13325#13325 http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13156/how-does-chesscube-com-rating-compare-to-uscf-and-fide-ratings/13189#13189

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately no 'good' way to convert from Glicko-2 to ELO. While a lot of people claim they have a formula, there really isn't any system that maintains the same invariants and distribution curve when converting.

That being said, there are some ways you could try and 'convert' your score. For example, you could find people on lichess who have similar ratings to yours, and see if they are USCF rated. Also, playing in a couple OTB tournaments would be more than enough to give you an accurate sense of what your ELO rating is around.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience, the ratings at lichess and most other online chess websites are drastically overrated in score. I know someone who uses lichess regularly. Although I don't know his USCF rating, he has a score of about 1600 on lichess. Having played him in real life, he seems to be more around 1000-1200 player.

Also, my rating on chess.com is about 1700, but in the last several times I've played in real tournaments, I seemed to be on par with those at 1500. (My USCF rating is 800, but that's a different story).